# How can i use Aws amplify and s3 storage to store items privately, but allow admin to access all files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify for my web application with Cognito for auth & also roles and s3 to store content per user.

Going through the documentation and [amplify storage](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/js/) docs. it was easy to configure private storage per user and was able to retrieve the data for that specific user as well.

How can I achieve getting files for all users if I am an "admin" user ( based on the Cognito role)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - found github link that says its not possible yet
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/5652

And this hidden FAQ
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/download/q/platform/js/#frequently-asked-questions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).